How to test the difference between two adverse impact ratios?
Let's define the adverse impact ratio as the hiring rate of minority candidates divided by the hiring rate of white candidates. (So the adverse impact ratio is the ratio of two ratios.)
I calculated adverse impact ratios for two jobs.
How might one test the null hypothesis that these two adverse impact ratios are equal?

Do you have multiple observed "adverse impact ratios" for each of those jobs? I don't see why you couldn't treat this as a binomial proportion of minority hires in each job, your construction essentially is that proportion expressed as odds.

@PBulls Does the ratio of two ratios follow the same distribution as a ratio of two frequencies?

What is your denominator in this rate; time, or total hires? Either way a log(it)-linked GLM, respectively Poisson/an extension or binomial, will let you make inference on their ratio (additive effects in log scale).

@PBulls  Hiring rate = # hired / # applicants    .  .  .  .
Adverse impact ratio = hiring rate for group A / hiring rate for group B

First, to bring some clarification from the comments: when you say "hiring rate" you mean number of hires over total number of applicants, i.e. this is a proportion. The ratio of two proportions is a relative risk, though it is quite common to treat this as an odds ratio. Either way you can pull the desired inference from a binomial GLM (aka. logistic regression).
Let's illustrate with a simulated example. We have three job categories, two of which have an equal "hiring rate" for both groups and the last one doesn't; it disfavours group 2 by $0.2/0.5=0.4$ in the relative risk (or "adverse impact ratio") scale. Note that I am not assuming any balance across jobs or groups, something you didn't really clarify how or whether you wanted to account for.
## True hiring rate for each group & job
probs <- matrix(
  c(.2, .2,
    .4, .4,
    .5, .2),
  ncol=2, byrow = TRUE,
  dimnames = list(paste0("job", 1:3), paste0("group", 1:2))
)

## Sample a bunch of applicants
set.seed(1)
n <- 1E6  ## Will make estimate reflect the truth almost certainly

group <- sample(seq_len(ncol(probs)), size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.9, .1))
job <- sample(seq_len(nrow(probs)), size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.2, .3, .5))
hired <- rbinom(n, 1, mapply(\(j,g) probs[j,g], j=job, g=group))

These data are now individual observations on whether an applicant got hired or not, but the next step will work just as well if you only have aggregate data (e.g. $r$ applicants out of $n$ from group x got hired for job y) using a slightly different input format. Let's fit the binomial GLM.
df <- data.frame(
  y = hired,
  Group = factor(group),
  Job = factor(job)
)

summary(fit <- glm(y ~ Group*Job, data=df, family=binomial))

#> glm(formula = y ~ Group * Job, family = binomial, data = df)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -1.380941   0.005891 -234.410   <2e-16 ***
#> Group2      -0.023079   0.018697   -1.234    0.217    
#> Job2         0.975371   0.007081  137.747   <2e-16 ***
#> Job3         1.378058   0.006601  208.760   <2e-16 ***
#> Group2:Job2  0.013416   0.022474    0.597    0.551    
#> Group2:Job3 -1.353002   0.021993  -61.521   <2e-16 ***

Model estimates are in the log-odds scale, so we can convert these back to probabilities using $\text{expit}(x)=1/(1+e^{-x})$ or the R function plogis.
For example, the intercept reflects the hiring rate for group 1, job 1 with estimate $\text{expit}(-1.381)\approx0.20085$, really quite close to the truth of $0.2$. The probability for the same group in job 2 is estimated as $\text{expit}(-1.381+0.975)\approx 0.39988$, again pretty much equal to $0.4$. You can go on to do this for every group/job in the model (perhaps not by hand).
What's really of interest are the parameters involving Group2 however, because these model the difference in hiring probability between groups (in the log-odds scale), as well as between jobs when including the interactions. Exponentiating these parameters will give you an odds ratio for a between-group, within-job comparison. The only one that's different -- as also shown by the other relevant parameters not being significantly different from 0 -- is Group2:Job3 or the difference between groups 1 and 2 within job 3, with an estimate of $\text{exp}(-1.353)\approx 0.2585$ and a true value of $\frac{0.2/(1-0.2)}{0.5/(1-0.5)}=0.25$. This is your statistical inference on a possible difference in hiring probabilities between groups.
Finally, you can turn these odds ratios back into relative risks (your original estimator) as long as you know at least one of the underlying absolute probabilities. I'll only leave a link to this question & answer and some code discussed therein:
epitools::probratio(fit)

#>             Relative risk  Std. Error     Z-value   p-value
#> Group2          0.9816835 0.014728570   1.2436003 0.2136467
#> Job2            1.9913323 0.010484420  94.5529059 0.0000000
#> Job3            2.4857341 0.012275550 121.0319827 0.0000000
#> Group2:Job2     1.0127574 0.016991530   0.7508104 0.4527668
#> Group2:Job3     0.4104494 0.007194461  81.9450622 0.0000000

The relative risk estimate is again quite close to the true value we saw above for all comparisons of groups & jobs.
